# Python: extra assignments in functions

Tags: memory-management, python, cpu-usage, assign

Considering the following as two versions of a very simple function in **Python**, the question is which one is preferred over another and why?

Is there any extra **memory usage** and or **CPU usage** for `case 1` compared to `case 2` in which additional assignment has been used?

**case 1:**

```
def f(x):
    y = x*x
    return y
```

**case 2:**

```
def f(x):
    return x*x
```

From my point of view, the `case 1` is clearer than the other one especially in case of complex computations and providing many returning objects. On the other hand, the `case 2` looks very compact and would be considered as a very attractive so. Since the simple is simply efficient. What do you think?

**update:**
I didn't know there is disassembler in Python! It was so amazing when I learned the answer of my question and the way to check similar ideas. Special appreciation.
`from dis import dis as dasm`
`dasm(f)`

Comment: Most of us think it doesn't matter.  Hence the votes to close.

Comment: +1 Simple and interesting question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to know what Python style is preferred, look at the code in the standard library:

```
$ grep return Lib/*py
```

You will see that the `case 2` style is the most common.

I personally use the assignment form only when the variable name is needed to add clarity to the code:

```
normalized_query = query.replace(' ', '').lower()
return normalized_query
```

This code introduces a *very small* bit of overhead for the assignment:

```
>>> def f(x):
        return x + 2

>>> def g(x):
        y = x + 2
        return y

>>> dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 BINARY_ADD          
              7 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis(g)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 BINARY_ADD          
              7 STORE_FAST               1 (y)

  3          10 LOAD_FAST                1 (y)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 3):

For the first one:

```
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
              7 STORE_FAST               1 (y)

  3          10 LOAD_FAST                1 (y)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

For the second one:

```
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, there's a (slight) cost in assigning something, even if you're not using it at all except for holding the value before returning.

Answer (score 3):

The preferred style is the one which is most readable for that particular function.  Once you have readable, correct code -- you are probably done.  *If* performance is an issue at that point, profile to see where the bottlenecks are, and work on those spots.

> It is easier to optimize correct code than to correct optimized code.